# ida decompiler output

Tags: ida, decompile, magic-number

```
double __cdecl sub_401660(float a1)
{
  double v1; // st7@1
  float v2; // ST00_4@1
  float v4; // [sp+8h] [bp+4h]@1
  float v5; // [sp+8h] [bp+4h]@1

  v1 = a1;
  LODWORD(v2) = 0x5F3759DF - (SLODWORD(a1) >> 1);
  v4 = 0.5 * a1;
  v5 = (1.5 - v4 * v2 * v2) * v2;
  return (float)(v1 * v5);
}
```

above function do some calculation using float number
i am not able to understand LODWORD line

Regards

Comment: `LODWORD` is the first 2 bytes of the `DWORD` and `HIDWORD` is the second 2 bytes of `DWORD`.. see those commands as just putting 2 pieces of a pizza pie together and then you read the whole pizza pie as a new number, and cast it to whatever datatype is suitable for it. I would just declare those macros in a new project and do some expirements with them both to understand their operation completely output a few `printf("%x\n", DWORDAnswer);` afterwards. (SLODWORD is signed version of LODWORD). Also you could replace all macro's with equivalent code to the macro to make it easier on the eye.

Answer (score 5):

The `0x5F3759DF` constant seems familiar...

It is the fast inverse square root algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

comparing against that code `SLODWORD` and `LODWORD` would be a bit-preserving conversion to an integral type.

The last line does `a1*invsqrt(a1)` which is equal to `sqrt(a1) * (sqrt(a1)/sqrt(a1))` so it ends up calculating the square root of the input parameter.

Comment: unable to under stand Floating point calculation

Comment: did you read the wiki article? In particular [the section that explains why it works?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Working_of_the_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

I use this line as reference to understand the hidden macros'

http://www.wekk.net/files/defcon/defs.h

```
double __cdecl sub_401660(float a1)
{
  double v1; // st7@1
  float v2; // ST00_4@1
  float v4; // [sp+8h] [bp+4h]@1
  float v5; // [sp+8h] [bp+4h]@1

  v1 = a1;
  LODWORD(v2) = 0x5F3759DF - (SLODWORD(a1) >> 1);
  v4 = 0.5 * a1;
  v5 = (1.5 - v4 * v2 * v2) * v2;
  return (float)(v1 * v5);
}
```

could be simplified easier on the eyes like this

```
double __cdecl sub_401660(float a1)
{
  double v1; // st7@1
  float v2; // ST00_4@1
  float v4; // [sp+8h] [bp+4h]@1
  float v5; // [sp+8h] [bp+4h]@1

  v1 = a1;
  *((_DWORD*)&(v2)) = 0x5F3759DF - (*((long*)&(a1)) >> 1);
  v4 = 0.5 * a1;
  v5 = (1.5 - v4 * v2 * v2) * v2;
  return (float)(v1 * v5);
}
```

or how I would do it..

```
double __cdecl sub_401660(float a1)
{
  double v1; // st7@1
  float v2; // ST00_4@1
  float v4; // [sp+8h] [bp+4h]@1
  float v5; // [sp+8h] [bp+4h]@1

  v1 = a1;
  *((unsigned int *)&(v2)) = 0x5F3759DF - (*((long*)&(a1)) >> 1);
  v4 = 0.5 * a1;
  v5 = (1.5 - v4 * v2 * v2) * v2;
  return (float)(v1 * v5);
}
```

**But this is how you do it if you are a hacker. Google.com search > 0x5F3759DF**

Find this link http://gostash.it/en/stashes/184

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
   long i;
   float x2, y;
   const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

   x2 = number * 0.5F;
   y = number;
   i = * ( long * ) &y; // evil floating point bit level hacking
   i = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 ); // what the fuck?
   y = * ( float * ) &i;
   y = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 1st iteration
   // y = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

   return y;
}
```

Comment: The link to wekk.net is broken. Your macro for LODWORD works perfectly for me. I wonder if you have another macro for HIDWORD, and other similar macros.

Answer (score 0):

SLODWORD(a1) returns the hex representation of a input read the `wiki-link` by ratchet freak and take a look at the poc below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long dodance(float number){
  float y  = number;
    long i  = * ( long * ) &y;
  return i;
}
void main (void) {  
  long a = dodance((float)3.2865);
  printf("%08X\n%f\n",a,*(float *)&a);
}
```

compile without optimization the above code using say

```
cl /Zi /EHsc /nologo /W4 /analyze *.cpp /link /RELEASE
```

and execute the resulting binary

```
magicnum.exe
40525604
3.286500
```

Compiling the enhanced code below you can see the maximum precision attainable by the 32 bit float is exhausted when the third term is evaluated in the series

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long dodance(float number)
{
  float y  = number;
    long i  = * ( long * ) &y;
  return i;
}
int main (int argc , char *argv[]) 
{
  if(argc != 3){printf ("usage %s <float> <int>\n",argv[0]);return 0;}
  float input = (float) atof(argv[1]);
  int term = atoi(argv[2]);
  long a = dodance(input);
  printf("%-10s= %08X\n%-10s= %f\n","hex",a,"float",*(float *)&a);
  long b = (0x5f3759df - (a >> 1));
  float c = *(float *)&b ;
  printf("%-10s= %08X\n%-10s= %f\n","hex",b,"~1stfloat",c);
  for(int i=0; i< term;i++) 
  {
    c = (float)(c * ( 1.5 - ( (input * 0.5) * c * c )) );
    printf("%-10s= %f\n","~nxtfloat",c);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

result

```
magicnum.exe
usage magicnum.exe <float> <int>

magicnum.exe 3.2 1
hex       = 404CCCCD
float     = 3.200000
hex       = 3F10F379
~1stfloat = 0.566215
~nxtfloat = 0.558877

magicnum.exe 3.2 2
hex       = 404CCCCD
float     = 3.200000
hex       = 3F10F379
~1stfloat = 0.566215
~nxtfloat = 0.558877
~nxtfloat = 0.559017

magicnum.exe 3.2 3
hex       = 404CCCCD
float     = 3.200000
hex       = 3F10F379
~1stfloat = 0.566215
~nxtfloat = 0.558877
~nxtfloat = 0.559017
~nxtfloat = 0.559017 <-- no improvement over the previous result
```

some theory

```
Newtons method is a proof and extension of binomial expansion theoram 
for fractions and negative numbers 
simplified binomial exapnsion for (1+x)^n = 1 + (n*x) + ((n*(n-1)/2)*x^2) + .......
we can derive an approximation of the  squareroot
sqrt(3.2)   = (4 - 0.8)^ 1/2  
        = 2 * ( 1 - 1/5) ^ 1/2
        = 2 * ( 1 + 1/2*(-1/5)  + (-1/8) * (1/25) + .....)
        = 2 * ( 1 - 1/10 - 1/200)
        = 2 * ( 200/200 - 20/200 - 1/200)
        = 2 * (179/200)
        = 2 * (0.895)
                = 1.79
1 / sqrt(3.2)   = 1 / 1.79
        = 0.55865921787709497206703910614525
using calc.exe 
3.2^-0.5    = 0.55901699437494742410229341718282
```